# Quickbooks PHP Integration error " No registered functions for action"

Tags: quickbooks

I want to connect to database of Quickbooks desktop version using PHP. For this Iam using the PHP dev kit downloaded from the link  http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/ .
 Here I connected to Quickbooks databse successfully using the given code in inside docs/example_app_web_connector  folder. In it adding of customer to databse is working. But when I tried to add function for fetching all employees from the database, it shows error like  No registered functions for action.
Where should I include this function to work perfectly??

In functions page I coded like this:-

function _quickbooks_customer_query_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID,        $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{

```
if (!empty($idents['iteratorRemainingCount']))
{
    // Queue up another request 
    $Queue = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::getInstance();
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER, null, 0, array( 'iteratorID' => $idents['iteratorID'] ));
}

// This piece of the response from QuickBooks is now stored in $xml. You 
//  can process the qbXML response in $xml in any way you like. Save it to 
//  a file, stuff it in a database, parse it and stuff the records in a 
//  database, etc. etc. etc. 
//  
// The following example shows how to use the built-in XML parser to parse 
//  the response and stuff it into a database. 

// Import all of the records
$errnum = 0;
$errmsg = '';
$Parser = new QuickBooks_XML_Parser($xml);
if ($Doc = $Parser->parse($errnum, $errmsg))
{
    $Root = $Doc->getRoot();
    $List = $Root->getChildAt('QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRs/CustomerQueryRs');

    foreach ($List->children() as $Customer)
    {
        $values = array(
            'ListID' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('CustomerRet ListID'),
            'FullName' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('CustomerRet FullName'),
            'FirstName' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('CustomerRet FirstName'),
            'LastName' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('CustomerRet LastName'),
            );
            print_r($values);
        foreach ($Customer->children() as $Node)
        {
            // Be careful! Custom field names are case sensitive! 
            if ($Node->name() === 'DataExtRet' and 
                $Node->getChildDataAt('DataExtRet DataExtName') == 'Your Custom Field Name Goes Here')
            {
                $values['Your Custom Field Names Goes Here'] = $Node->getChildDataAt('DataExtRet DataExtValue');
            }
        }
        $fullname=$values['FullName'];
        $firstname=$values['FirstName'];
        $lastname=$values['LastName'];
        $listid=$values['ListID'];

        // Do something with that data... 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `my_customer_table` (name,fname,lname,quickbooks_listid) VALUES ('$fullname','$firstname','$lastname','$listid') ");   
    exit;     
    }
}

return true;
```

}

And in main code called like this
:-
require_once dirname(**FILE**) . '/config.php';

```
$Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
$fg=$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER);
```

Comment: This probably means that you didn't define your function, or register it in $map. But... POST YOUR CODE so that we can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for trouble.. atlast got it... Actually In that folder their is a file named qbwc.php that I didnt noticed. In it we have to add functions inside $map variable...

```
    <?php
  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';

       /**
            * Require some callback functions
               */ 
      require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/functions.php';

             // Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
      $map = array(
QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),
  QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_query_request', '_quickbooks_customer_query_response' ),
);

    // This is entirely optional, use it to trigger actions when an error is   returned by QuickBooks
      $errmap = array(
'*' => '_quickbooks_error_catchall',                // Using a key value of '*' will catch any errors which were not caught by another error handler
);

           // An array of callback hooks
               $hooks = array(
                              );

             // Logging level
                 $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEVELOP;       // Use this level until you're sure everything works!!!

           // What SOAP server you're using 
 $soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;       // A pure-PHP SOAP          server (no PHP ext/soap extension required, also makes debugging easier)

       $soap_options = array(       // See http://www.php.net/soap
);

        $handler_options = array(
'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false, 
);      // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Server/Handlers.php file

         $driver_options = array(       // See the comments in the                QuickBooks/Driver/<YOUR DRIVER HERE>.php file ( i.e. 'Mysql.php', etc. )
);

          $callback_options = array(
);

         // Create a new server and tell it to handle the requests
        // __construct($dsn_or_conn, $map, $errmap = array(), $hooks =  array(), $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL, $soap = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP, $wsdl = QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options = array(), $handler_options = array(),    $driver_options = array(), $callback_options = array()
```

$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks,     $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options,       $driver_options, $callback_options);
  $response = $Server->handle(true, true);
?>